# Сейчас занимаюсь парсингом сайта Grailed. И мне при GET запросе выдает не весь html сайта

Tags: html, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Всем здраствуйте. Для парсинга использую python и библиотеку requests. При парсинге сайта получаю <Response [200]> и html код(казалось бы все хорошо). но когда начинаю проверять этот код, вижу что туда не попал ни один из div'ов которые мне нужны были(классы с объявлениями о продажи одежды). полученный код заканчивается строкой " performance.mark("scripts done blocking") " . что нужно сделать, чтобы получить весь код?
Оставлю тут ссылку на сайт, вдруг кто-то сам решит попробовать: https://www.grailed.com/shop

Comment: использую UserAgent(следовательно, и заголовки), но это никак не помогает. при чем, если не использовать их, то выдает <Response [403]>. видимо, у сайта какая-то мощная защита

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: сайт динамический плюс защита от ботов. Я вам рекомендую перейти на селениюм

Comment: или покурите что-нибудь типа `requests-html`

Comment: requests-html тоже не работает :(